# Alternatives to Deprec Deployment with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I have been using [Deprec](http://deprec.failmode.com/) with Slicehost for a bit now but it seems like development isn't that active anymore.

What do you use for automating most of the deployment steps for Rails these days?  I'm using Slicehost.

Comment: Deprec is really awesome tool if you want to take a max control on what happens on servers. It should fit well for us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried them, but Rails core member Josh Peek has a [set of Capistrano recipes in his GitHub repository](http://github.com/josh/slicehost) for setting up a slice. Could be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

While I still use deprec for a lot of things, Phusion Passenger has made installing a Rails stack so simple I find it easier to maintain a simple list of commands. I use this on Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) amd64

```
apt-get install build-essential git-core mysql-client apache2 apache2-prefork-dev libapr1-dev libmysqlclient15-dev librmagick-ruby libmagick9-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev imagemagick libcurl4-openssl-dev libreadline-ruby1.8

wget http://rubyenterpriseedition.googlecode.com/files/ruby-enterprise_1.8.7-2011.02_amd64_ubuntu10.04.deb
dpkg -i ruby-enterprise_1.8.7-2011.02_amd64_ubuntu10.04.deb

gem install passenger bundler
passenger-install-apache2-module --auto

# Copy configs generated by previous command to 
#   /etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.{load,conf}

a2enmod passenger
a2enmod rewrite
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```